# General error: 25 bind or column index out of range

Tags: pdo, sqlite

Using SQLite and PDO. I'm quite new to PDO so I could use some help here. I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 25 bind or column index out of range
```

Here is my code:

```php
// db.php
function dbh($sql, $db = "", $nsx = "") {
    $db = ($db) ? $db : "mydb";
    $db = $db.".sqlite";
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:$db");
        $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        // id, title, desc, cost, album, version, added
        $dbh->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
                        `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                        `title` TEXT,
                        `desc` TEXT,
                        `cost` TEXT,
                        `album` TEXT,
                        `version`TEXT,
                        `added` DATETIME
                    )");
        //$mem = new PDO('sqlite::memory');
        //$mem->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

        $res = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        //var_dump($nsx);
        $res->execute($nsx);

        if (!is_array($nsx)) {
            return $res->fetchAll();
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}

// products.php
$sql = "INSERT INTO `products` (title, desc, cost, album, version, added) VALUES (:title,:desc,:album,:version,:cost,:date)";
$nsx = array(
':title'   => $i['addon']['title'][$k],
':desc'    => $i['addon']['desc'][$k],
':cost'    => $i['addon']['cost'][$k],
':album'   => $album,
':version' => '1.0',
':added'   => $date,
);
$dbh = dbh($sql,"",$nsx);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You bind `:added`, but did not specify it in the VALUES list: `(:title,:desc,:album,:version,:cost,:date)`. Instead you specified `:date` which is not bound by your array.

Comment: If you get the above mentioned error with an `UPDATE` statement, it is the same cause as described by this answer

Comment: You may also see this error if your query uses quotes around bound values (binding the values will handle quoting for you). Delete the quotes and the query should run okay.